# Remove all lists of multiple sets where the specific index is same

Tags: python, python-2.7

Object: Given multiple sets of 2d arrays, remove all items in each array that share a common value in a specific index in any of the arrays.

The data is large, around 20 groups, with 200k arrays each, of which large amounts of data are in each array.

What I know with two sets

```
a = [['a',10,11],['b',10,11],['c',10,11]]
b = [['e',10,11],['a',12,11],['f',10,11]]
c = [['aa',10,11],['b',10,11],['cc',10,11]]

first = []
second = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    first.append(a[i][0])
for i in range(len(b)):
    second.append(b[i][0])

AA = set(map(tuple,first))
BB = set(map(tuple,second))

print AA
print BB
print BB.symmetric_difference(AA)
```

I can get a new set that contains the unique items based on the first index of each item(array) in the array.  However, I would like to remove the items from each set that exist in any other sets, not just between two, and not just make a new set.

If I can get the index of all items in `a` that match items in `b` or `c`, I can delete them.  I could do this with loops, but that seems inefficient (not vectorized?).

Given:

```
a = [['a',10,11],['b',10,11],['c',10,11]]
b = [['e',10,11],['a',12,11],['f',10,11]]
c = [['aa',10,11],['b',10,11],['cc',10,11]]
```

The output would be

```
a = [['c',10,11]]
b = [['e',10,11],['f',10,11]]
c = [['aa',10,11],['cc',10,11]]
```

Comment: " However, I would like to remove the items from each set that exist in all other sets,"  By your example, I'd say you mean *any* other set.

Comment: what would be your output if a had another ['c', 1, 0], for example, in the list of lists?

Comment: @Jblasco Yes. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a counter dict to get the count of how many times each first element appears in each sublist then only keep the sublists that have a first element that appears once.

```
from collections import Counter

# count how many times each sublists first element appears in all sublists
keys = Counter((ele[0] for sub in (a,b,c) for ele in sub))
for l in (a, b, c):
    for sub in reversed(l):
        # if the count is not 1 then it is not unique so remove it
        if keys[sub[0]] != 1:
            l.remove(sub)

print (a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[['c', 10, 11]]
[['e', 10, 11], ['f', 10, 11]]
[['aa', 10, 11], ['cc', 10, 11]]
```

If you want to keep the original lists just append to new lists instead of removing from the original.

If a had another sublist with `c` as the first element you would end up with an empty list:

```
a = [['a',10,11],['b',10,11],['c',10,11],["c",3,4]]
b = [['e',10,11],['a',12,11],['f',10,11]]
c = [['aa',10,11],['b',10,11],['cc',10,11]]
```

Output:

```
[]
[['e', 10, 11], ['f', 10, 11]]
[['aa', 10, 11], ['cc', 10, 11]]
```

Comment: that's on the line of what I was thinking (although much more elegant I must admit), and the reason I asked what happens if a = [] has a second "c". In your way of doing it both "c" would disappear, right?

Comment: @Jblasco, it iterates over every sublist so if you added a c to the first array then it would end up empty which I presume is correct? As far as reversed goes you should not remove elements from a list you are iterating over unless you either make a copy or more efficiently use reversed, otherwise you can end up removing the wrong elements

Comment: Yes, the OP answered that is the correct behavior, to remove both. I didn't know the trick of reversing the list, that makes a lot of sense now, thanks!

Comment: @Jblasco, no worries.

Comment: the use of reversed is nice!